# How to append along row axis in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following code, how can I append these files along row axis?

```
path = "/home/user/Desktop/dataset4"
for files in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
    np.append(files,axis=0)
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question. It's not clear what your are asking.

Comment: I want to collect these files along row axis. if I use store=[], then apply a for loop using store.append() it collects these files in a list. But I want to collect then in rows. Each files is 2 dimensional numpy array. If I use np.append(files,files+1, axis=0) it is giving me error that string and integer can not be concatenated. So how should I proceed?

Comment: Edit your Question and add some example data.